# How to guide user through multiple unrelated forms

Tags: 7, forms

I have a content type with a term reference field. I want to give user a convenient way of grouping multiple nodes of that type together. I see it like this:

1. The user creates a first node
2. When he goes to a node page, he sees a link "subjoin another document"
3. After pressing it the taxonomy term creation form is shown, user fills required fields
4. After saving the term he gets redirected to node creation form
5. Second node is created, taxonomy term fields of both nodes point to newly created taxonomy term

What puzzles me is how it's best to implement such a multiphase logic in Drupal, when we need to guide the user through several unrelated forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I implemented this functionality in a custom module. Together with prepopulate it allows to conveniently link nodes together without manually creating taxonomy terms.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['continue_with/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Continue with',
    'description' => 'Creates new story and links existent material to it',
    'page callback' => 'vidsboku_custom_continue_with',
    'page arguments' => array(1,2),
    'access callback' => true,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function my_module_continue_with($content_type, $nid) {
  $existing = node_load($nid);

  if(!is_object($existing)) {
    drupal_goto("");
  }

  if (empty($existing->field_story)) {
    if (!node_access('update', $existing)  || !(user_access('administer taxonomy') || user_access('edit terms in 4'))) {
      drupal_set_message('Insufficient permissions','error');
      drupal_goto("");
      return;
    }

    $term = new stdClass();
    $term->vid = 4; // Vocabulary ID for Story
    $term->name = $existing->title; // Term Name

    taxonomy_term_save($term);
    $tid = $term->tid;

    $existing->field_story = array('und' => array(0 => array('tid' => $tid)));
    node_save($existing);
  } else
    $tid = $existing->field_story['und'][0]['tid'];

  drupal_goto('node/add/' . $content_type, array('query' =>
                                                  array('edit[field_story][und]' => $tid)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you might find [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) and [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module useful for this.

Comment: Completely forgot about the relation module! Many thanks. I see there is great progress since last spring. Will try to adapt a relation-select module, it's demonstrated in this great screencast: http://dev.nodeone.se/en/relation-select